# SQL Server Profiler - Strange Duration, StartTime is greater than EndTime

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I did a lot of searching but still could not figure out why SQL Server Profiler shown the very unusual numbers.

Scenario: Our web application thrown a SqlException complaining timeout expired (once in a while), so i decided to use the SQL Profiler to trace the long running query. But the result turned out pretty strange, the Duration was a very huge number and StartTime was greater than EndTime.

I really appreciate for any advice of where i should further look into.

(Please take a look at the attached image since i don't have enough reputation to post images).

Thank you.

[image: SQL Server Profiler]

**Updated:**
We found the long running query which took 4 minutes to be completed, but SQL Profiler is still showing those Audit Logout events with the "overflow" Duration even the problematic query is not running.

Comment: How long is the query actually taking? As far as I know, profiler displays duration in milliseconds to the GUI. If that duration is in fact in milliseconds, execution time would be over half a million years. Even if its in microseconds, execution time works out to over 213 days.

Comment: @mdsimps99 i'm still looking for the long running query, but as you can see it's the Audit Logout events that showing the unusual numbers and they show up multiple times within a second. And yes, the duration looks like an overflown number, and i think the catch is in StartTime and EndTime somehow...

Comment: This may help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/tracking-down-application-timeout-errors-in-sql-server

Comment: @Alex thank you for the link, but that's not our target. We found the long running query which took 4 mins to be completed, but SQL Profiler is still showing these Audit Logout events with overflown duration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.  It's a question about an administrative tool.