# SQL Profiler shows a StartTime greater than EndTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I'm using SQL Profiler to check some long run query. Somehow I see some entries in SQL profiler show StartTime that are greater than the EndTime, and the duration value is obviously overflow. 
Why is this happening? Any advice? 
Thanks in advance.

[image: SQL Profiler]

[image: Some Examples]

Comment: Can you post the Trace XML for that or a similar record?

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of another unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846829/sql-server-profiler-strange-duration-starttime-is-greater-than-endtime.

Comment: @DanielGimenez yes I saw that question, but it gets no answer and the discussion in the comment doesn't provide many help.

Comment: @DanielGimenez added some examples of this issue.

Comment: I think this would be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks!